# Can a plant be grown in a vacuum chamber

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, environment, flora

Thats my question please answer it

Comment: Welcome Matthew. Please take the [tour] and at your leisure read-up in the [help] about how we work. At the moment your question doesn't offer many details to base a meaningful answer on. You can [edit] it though.

Answer (score 1):

## No

Plant cells respire just like (ish) animal cells do, taking in oxygen from the air and emitting carbon dioxide.  Photosynthesis also requires carbon dioxide from the surrounding air and releases oxygen gas.  In a vacuum neither of these processes can occur, so the plant will not survive.

Comment: Technically, I agree with @AlexP's comment above: It's a _vacuum_ chamber, not necessarily an _evacuated_ vacuum chamber. In the former case, $CO_2$ will be available. The question lacks sufficient detail

Comment: @nzaman, it should be obvious that the OP was thinking of an evacuated vacuum chamber, or he would have written "steel box" or something like that.

Comment: @o.m.: Considering that all he said was: `Thats my question please answer it`, I'm supporting trolling answers